# A good default background image type and size

Tags: css, gimp

I'm using this to set my background image.

```
body{
  background: url('path_to_image');
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

I'm happy with how `background-size` handles small differences in screen size.

I'm designing my background image in gimp to be a blue abstract image.  What size would be good to handle the most common screen size ( in pixel width and height ), and what is a good image format to export it in?

Here is an example of one background image I tested with:

http://dooid.me/images/uploads/1334771136brentreader.gif

Most common screen size reported ( [link here](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_resolution_higher.asp) )  by browsers appears to be:

```
1366x768
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1366x768 sounds good if that's the most common screen resolution these days. File type should be .jpg if your image has many gradients and subtle details, or .png (or .gif) if your image is mostly solid shapes with no anti-aliasing, such as pixel-art. Always keep in mind both the quality and the file size when exporting your image !

It's also good that you're using an abstract image for your background, as using `background-size:100%` can lead to stretching in unintended resolutions (which would look silly with more figurative pictures !).